# Terminologies in Oracle-SQL and MySQL | Mutiple Database, Mutiple instances comparsion

Tags: oracle, schema, instance

In Oracle-SQL:

- Database = set of physical files on disk
- Instance = processes, daemons, and memory structures (i.e state of operation)
- Schema = collection of database objects, including logical structures such as tables and indexes, etc.
- Schema objects = any/combination of objects of Schema(collection) i.e tables,views,index etc.

In MySQL:

- Database/schema(can be cross-used) = synonymous to the schema of Oracle-SQL
- Instance = similar to Oracle-SQL instance
- schema-objects/databse-objects =  synonymous to the schema objects of Oracle-SQL

I have the following doubts:

[From MySQL glossary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_schema)

> For example, in the Oracle Database product, a schema represents only a part of a database: the tables and other objects owned by a single user.

Why "only a part of a database"?("database" is used in the context of MySQL if I am not wrong)

From [asktom oracle forum](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1631683800346891854) what I interpret is:

1. An instance can mount and open only a single database, "ever" -> (because the new instance is created each time DB opened and the instance is destroyed when DB is closed
2. A database may be mounted and manipulated by one or more(using RAC) instances.

Is this still relevant (as of 19c and 21c)? if not, why?

I am confused with #2, are they talking about "one after other" or "together at any particular point of time" (in case of both with and without RAC)?

can I mount multiple databases(in the context of oracle) on the same oracle instance without using RAC?

can a machine/server can have multiple instances using Oracle software?

While in the case of MySQL:

- An instance can mount many databases but work on only one at any given time.
- A database may be mounted and manipulated by one or more instances at any given time.
- A machine/server can have multiple instances

is this correct? if not, why?

does most of RDBMS fall in one or the other classification?

please correct me if any of my interpretation or statement is False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking for Oracle RDBMS:

> Why "only a part of a database"?("database" is used in the context of MySQL if I am not wrong)

This was from Oracle RDBMS documentation, not MySQL, so used in the context of Oracle, a single schema is only a part of a database instance.

> From asktom oracle forum what I interpret is:
>
> 1. An instance can mount and open only a single database, "ever" -> (because the new instance is created each time DB opened and the instance is destroyed when DB is closed
> 2. A database may be mounted and manipulated by one or more(using RAC) instances
>
> Is this still relevant (as of 19c and 21c)? if not, why?

Yes, this is still relevent. One instance can open one set of database files (data files, redo logs, control files, temporary data files, etc.). In the case of RAC, the database files are shared by multiple hosts, so one instance on each RAC host can open the same set of files simultaneously.

> can I mount multiple databases(in the context of oracle) on the same oracle instance without using RAC?
>
> can a machine/server can have multiple instances using Oracle software?

An instance (set of processes) can only open one set of database files, but you can run multiple independent instances (i.e. each with their own independent files) on the same host. Each independent instance can be a separate version of Oracle, as well. RAC allows you to open the *same* set of database files across multiple hosts simultaneously, so that you can scale your resources horizontally as well as vertically.

In the case of MySQL, it is possible to run multiple instances on the same host. See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716542/run-multiple-mysql-server-on-a-single-machine. A database (schema) would only be presented by one instance at a time, unless clustered, similar to Oracle RAC (other databases do not cluster the same as Oracle RAC, however - most replicate datafiles and transactions between hosts, where RAC actually shares them).